# Bootstrap 4 - Media Item and making the grid responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have 12 media items that I want to display.

On a medium screen and above grid I want to display 3 columns and 4 rows.
On a small screen I want to display 2 columns and 6 rows.
On an extra-small screen I want to display 1 columns and 12 rows.

I'm not sure how to structure my col-* and list items to achieve this.

Can someone help to get my items in order please.

```html
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-4">

                <ul class="list-unstyled">

                    <li class="media">
                        <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-chart_pie.png" alt="Google Analytics">
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h6>Google Analytics</h6>
                            <p>Automatic Google Analytics link tagging to easily track your sales and conversions.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="media">
                        <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-mouse.png" alt="Link Clicks">
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h6>Link Clicks</h6>
                            <p>Learn what subscribers are interested in by which links were popular, who clicked.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="media">
                        <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-flag_red.png" alt="Spam Complaints">
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h6>Spam Complaints</h6>
                            <p>Integration with Yahoo!, Hotmail and more mean we can report on complaints.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="media">
                        <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-table.png" alt="Export to Excel">
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h6>Export to Excel</h6>
                            <p>Export all reporting data to Excel for offline storage or further analysis.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div> <!-- /col -->

            <div class="col-sm-4">

                <ul class="list-unstyled">

                    <li class="media">
                        <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-arrow_right_curved.png" alt="Forward to a friend">
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h6>Forward to a friend</h6>
                            <p>Track viral activity by seeing exactly which subscribers forward on to a friend.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="media">
                        <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-person_cross.png" alt="Bounces">
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h6><a href="report-bounces.php">Bounces</a></h6>
                            <p>See who bounced and why, and we'll figure out if we should try again or remove.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="media">
                        <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-gear.png" alt="API">
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h6>Access with our API</h6>
                            <p>Sync and display campaign reports in your own apps using our own API.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="media">
                        <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-clock.png" alt="Activity Timeline">
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h6>Activity Timeline</h6>
                            <p>See your complete history with every subscriber in a handy timeline.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div> <!-- /col -->

            <div class="col-sm-4">

                <ul class="list-unstyled">

                    <li class="media">
                        <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-chart_bar.png" alt="Compare Campaigns">
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h6>Compare Campaigns</h6>
                            <p>Spot trends by comparing opens, clicks and more for multiple campaigns at once.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="media">
                        <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-orb_cross.png" alt="Unsubscribes">
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h6><a href="report-bounces.php">Unsubscribes</a></h6>
                            <p>We make sure you don't accidentally try and send to them again in the future.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="media">
                        <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-people.png" alt="Client Report Access">
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h6>Client Report Access</h6>
                            <p>Let your clients access the reports on any campaigns you send for them.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="media">
                        <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-flag_green.png" alt="delivery">
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h6>Top-notch delivery</h6>
                            <p>Authentication, relationships with ISPs and more ensure your emails are delivered.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div> <!-- /col -->
        </div> <!-- /row -->
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using bootstrap v4 based on the mr-3 and d-flex classes.

You can achieve this layout by replacing `col-sm-4` with `col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4`

Example code. This will show 1 column on extra small screens, 2 columns on small screens and three columnns on medium and larger screens.

```
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">

            <ul class="list-unstyled">

                <li class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-chart_pie.png" alt="Google Analytics">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h6>Google Analytics</h6>
                        <p>Automatic Google Analytics link tagging to easily track your sales and conversions.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-mouse.png" alt="Link Clicks">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h6>Link Clicks</h6>
                        <p>Learn what subscribers are interested in by which links were popular, who clicked.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-flag_red.png" alt="Spam Complaints">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h6>Spam Complaints</h6>
                        <p>Integration with Yahoo!, Hotmail and more mean we can report on complaints.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-table.png" alt="Export to Excel">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h6>Export to Excel</h6>
                        <p>Export all reporting data to Excel for offline storage or further analysis.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div> <!-- /col -->

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">

            <ul class="list-unstyled">

                <li class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-arrow_right_curved.png" alt="Forward to a friend">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h6>Forward to a friend</h6>
                        <p>Track viral activity by seeing exactly which subscribers forward on to a friend.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-person_cross.png" alt="Bounces">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h6><a href="report-bounces.php">Bounces</a></h6>
                        <p>See who bounced and why, and we'll figure out if we should try again or remove.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-gear.png" alt="API">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h6>Access with our API</h6>
                        <p>Sync and display campaign reports in your own apps using our own API.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-clock.png" alt="Activity Timeline">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h6>Activity Timeline</h6>
                        <p>See your complete history with every subscriber in a handy timeline.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div> <!-- /col -->

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">

            <ul class="list-unstyled">

                <li class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-chart_bar.png" alt="Compare Campaigns">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h6>Compare Campaigns</h6>
                        <p>Spot trends by comparing opens, clicks and more for multiple campaigns at once.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-orb_cross.png" alt="Unsubscribes">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h6><a href="report-bounces.php">Unsubscribes</a></h6>
                        <p>We make sure you don't accidentally try and send to them again in the future.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-people.png" alt="Client Report Access">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h6>Client Report Access</h6>
                        <p>Let your clients access the reports on any campaigns you send for them.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="images/icons/icon-48x48-flag_green.png" alt="delivery">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h6>Top-notch delivery</h6>
                        <p>Authentication, relationships with ISPs and more ensure your emails are delivered.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div> <!-- /col -->
    </div> <!-- /row -->
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work. it keeps the list in three separate divs, that whilst they change width on different screens, when I goto a small screen, the last div, is then placed beneath the others two side by side div and I get a two columns, the first one has 8 items in it and the second has 4.

On a small display I want two columns with 6 in each.

The secret here I think is to target the list items and not the surrounding divs.